# Adding an action bar for iOS in Titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am creating a cross platform app with Titanium. The thing is that I call a js with the following code:

```
bot_import.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ModImport = require('ModImport');
    var importPage = new ModImport();
    importPage.open();
});
```

The thing is that in ModImport.js I cannot use the following statement in the end: 
    importsWin.open();

Instead of that, I must use:

```
return importsWin;
```

But, in order to make an action bar for iOS I had to use this code:

```
var wini = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window : importsWin
});
```

The problem is that if I do a:

```
return wini;
```

I got a msg in the app: "Undefinied is not a function", however, if I use:

```
return importsWin;
```

I do not have any issue but the action bar in iOS does not show up.

I hope you understand my problem and I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that instead of `open.importsWin();` you mean `importsWin.open();`?

If not, then that's the reason you get undefined, because nowhere do you define an `open` object that has a `importsWin()` method.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong here thanks. However with that structure I can`t use the importsWin.open() as far as I know, I have to finish with return nameOfWindow.

Comment: That I can't say much about with the code you shared in your question. That's too little context.